# how to save cv::mat with type 32FC1 to file

Tags: opencv

I have a cv::mat depth image.It is of type CV_32FC1(when i tried test_mat.type it gave me 5 which stands for 32Fc1).
 I want to save it as a 32FC1 image. How do I specify the format while using imwrite?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/32357875/5294258

Comment: did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735863/opencv-save-cv-32fc1-images

Comment: @sturkmen does that answer really solve this?

Comment: surely yes. i think @Miki will confirm me.